# How to addView into Bottom bar

Tags: android

I want to addView into Bottom bar. I used this Bottom bar liabrary. `compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:1.2.1'`. The problem is when i add view, the view appears at top of screen rather than bottom. Kindly tell me how to add and show view in Bottom bar at bottom side of screen accurately.

```
final BottomBar bottomBar = BottomBar.attachShy((CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinatorlayout), findViewById(R.id.myScrollingContent), savedInstanceState);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
        addMainTypeView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.add_main_type, null);
        bottomBar.addView(addMainTypeView);
```

add_main_type.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/five_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/add_main_type"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="bottom bar"
            android:hint="@string/enter_type"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried to post the question in the library's page?

Comment: i think its enough to understand

Comment: no, i've not tried yet

Comment: afaik, BottomBar is a LinearLayout (with horizontal orientation in phone and vertical in tablet), so adding view will be added as last child of linearlayout

Answer (score 0):

You might try the new [Bottom Sheet](https://material.google.com/components/bottom-sheets.html) component in [Android Design Support library]:

Tutorials here: http://www.truiton.com/2016/07/android-bottom-sheet-example/

[image]

Comment: you should note this in your original post!